# How to Correctly Display ManyToMany ID Matching List in Django?

Tags: python, django

How to correctly display ManyToMany ID matching list?

My report list (weekly, monthly etc):

```
Car Number 1:
-customer (date, name etc) 
-customer (date, name etc)

Car Number 2:    
-customer (date, name etc) 
-customer (date, name etc)
```

My Models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name ...

class Reservation(model.Models):
    cars = models.ManyToManyField('Car', related_name="reservation")
    customerinfo = ...
```

As each customer can reserve multiple cars, I have to use M2M field.

Now displaying the list :

```
{% for car in cars %}
<h1>{{ car.name }}</h1>
    {% for reservation in reservations %}
        {% for reservationcar in reservation.cars.all %}
            {% if reservationcar.id = car.id %}
                <h2>{{ reservation.cusotmerinfo }}</h2>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, the above works, but doesnt look right and looks quite dirty.

Is there a better, cleaner, shorter way to accomplish that?

Comment: shouldn't be the car have a ManyToMany with the user? Not sure you need that middle table.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany check this out.

Comment: @EsseTi I think your solution is just what I need. Can you comment how will the code in my template look if a create a `through` table called `ReservedCars` with foreign keys linking `Car` and `Reservation` models?

Comment: did, check it out. it's not complex. Give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The M-M is "wrong" you can user [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)
It will looks like something like this (not tested)

```
class User(models.Model):
    .. any data you need ..

class Car(models.Model):
    .. any data you need ..
    reservations = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Reservations')


class Reservations(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    .. any data you need ..
```

You can probably place the reservations in the user and change the ref.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have pretty much implemented this structure. Now back to my original question, how do I query that without using pretty much the same query code in my template as the original M2M post.

Comment: The thing is, when I do `{% for car in car.reservation.all %}` I do get all car reservations regardless of their reservation date. I'm already running two queries. `cars = Car.objects.all()` and `reservations = Reservation.objects.filter(mydates)` and I'm trying to accomplish the OP without the `IF` line.

Comment: Got it figured out, at the end, I have to run another query to get the reservations and filter them out using the `IF` statement as I'm unaware if there is any better solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's quicker to do a query in the views.py and add the resulting queryset to the context of the view. Or use reverse by related_name. Also with the suggested through table. All you do in templates should be minimized for performance. So do the real 'math' in python (e.g. in the views class).

in the example given also in the comments:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

- person is the customer
- group is the car
- membership is the reservation

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Can you comment how will this setup change the query code in my template in my original post?